# Bad Credentials while sending message with nexmo

Tags: php, api, sms, vonage

I am creating message application but getting Bad Credentials error and message is not sending.Please tell me what to do. I put Nexmo api and secret correct then what is problem
$nexmo_sms = new NexmoMessage('xxxx', 'xxxx');
please tell me solution.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you may need to double check the api_key and api_secret parameters. I used to get Bad Credentials error. Upon checking the parameters, I saw that I accidentally entered the api_key by mistake. Entering the correct api_key fixed the Bad Credential error.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample of how you send a SMS in PHP using Nexmo's SMS API call

```
<?php
$url = 'https://rest.nexmo.com/sms/json?' . http_build_query([
        'api_key' => API_KEY,
        'api_secret' => API_SECRET,
        'to' => YOUR_NUMBER,
        'from' => NEXMO_NUMBER,
        'text' => 'Hello from Nexmo'
    ]);

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

You have to make sure you have all the required fields: 
**api_key**, **api_secret**, **to**, **from** *(your Nexmo number in international format)*, & body of the **text**.

Please check your application and see if all the required parameters are there and correct. If they are all correct, please reply with your code (go ahead and redact your **api_key** & **api_secret** ) and I can try and help you out from there!

*Full disclosure, I work at Nexmo*.